# WordPress CPT show content in div on same page when link clicked

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress Custom Post Type called vacancies.
On my vacancies archive page, I wish to have a list of the latest vacancies with small excerpts (which I have).

When I click the "read more" link under each vacancy, I want the content of the CPT to appear on the same page in another div. When I click another link, I then want it to change the div content to the new CPT content, without reloading the archive page.

I hope this makes sense?

```
<ul class="vacancies-list">
    <li>
        <h2>Vacancy title</h2>
        <p>Vacancy CPT Excerpt</p>
        <a href="">Read more</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h2>Vacancy title</h2>
        <p>Vacancy CPT Excerpt</p>
        <a href="">Read more</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h2>Vacancy title</h2>
        <p>Vacancy CPT Excerpt</p>
        <a href="">Read more</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="vacancy-content">
    <p>When "read more clicked, I want content of CPT pulled here</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

Either Add an AJAX Funtion, which dynamically loads the contents of your cpt when users click the "Read More". It basically is a way to execute a regular WP_Query statement using JavaScript. You can find plenty of goog tutorials online on how to implement such a thing based on your included libraries. Personally I tend to use jQuery and it's .ajax() function. - This method will ensure you have a quick initial load time of your page but there will be a slight delay between clicking "Read More" and the content being displayed.

Or Load the content in a hidden div and then just toggle the visiblity of said div using JS. Add a unique identifier to your list-items. This should then help you identify the post and then show the corresponding content in the Vacancy-content. Something like this to clarify:

```
<ul class="vacancies-list">
    <li data-post="1">
        <h2>Vacancy title</h2>
        <p>Vacancy CPT Excerpt</p>
        <a href="">Read more</a>
    </li>
    <li data-post="2">
        <h2>Vacancy title</h2>
        <p>Vacancy CPT Excerpt</p>
        <a href="">Read more</a>
    </li>
    <li data-post="3">
        <h2>Vacancy title</h2>
        <p>Vacancy CPT Excerpt</p>
        <a href="">Read more</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="vacancy-content">
   <div class="content post-1">Lorem Ipsum</div>
   <div class="content post-2">Lorem Ipsum</div>
   <div class="content post-3">Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

All content in vacancy-content is hidden. On ReadMore-Click hide all content and then show the content based on the li's data-attribute.

This Method will cause a slightly higher intial load time but will display the new content immediatly